# How does an empty regular expression evaluate?

Tags: regex, parsing, syntax, grammar

For doing something like the following:

```
select regexp_matches('X', '');
```

Is a regular expression of an empty-string defined behavior? If so, how does it normally work?

In other words, which of the following is the base production (ignoring some of the advanced constructs such as repetition, grouping, etc.)?

```
regex
    : atom+
    ;
```

Or:

```
regex
    : atom*
    ;
```

As an example:

[image]

regex101 shows no match for all 7 flavors, but Postgres returns `true` on `select regexp_matches('X', '');`.

Comment: What makes you think it would not be defined behaviour? The blank string is found in every string before and after (ie between) every character. What are you asking?

Comment: @Bohemian PostgreSQL [`regexp_matches`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) has parameters reversed to most; the string is first, then the regex. So in this question it's the regex which is empty

Comment: @Bohemian so are you saying that an empty regex is treated as the empty string? If so, why doesn't it produce the same value, as say doing `|` in regex101, where it would match 'between every char' ?

Comment: Since there is no `atom` in the regex, only the latter *could* apply. It seems Javascript, PHP and python all return a zero-length match

Comment: "regex101 shows no match for all 7 flavors" - that site isn't going to do anything until you enter a nonempty regex. That's a site UX decision, not a regex thing.

Comment: @David542 you might want an edit which says that it's the regex which is the empty string; almost all `regex_match` functions have the regex first

Comment: If regex101 thinks your regex doesn't match the string, it will say "Your regular expression does not match the subject string.". It doesn't say that when the regex field is empty.

Comment: Regex101 not respecting the blank regex as valid input is reasonable, because it's a nonsense regex; a curiosity that has no useful purpose.

Comment: Regex101 correctly accepts `()` or `(?:)` as matching the empty string; those are logically identical to the empty regex. I think it's just using an empty regex input box as an indication that you haven't entered a regex yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty regex, by definition, matches the empty string. In a substring match (which is what PostgreSQL's `regex_match` performs), the match always succeeds since the empty string is a substring of every string, including itself. So it's not a very useful query, but it should work with any regex implementation. (It might be more useful as a full string match, but string equality would also work and probably with less overhead.)

One aspect of empty matches which does vary between regex implementations is how they interact with the "global" (repeated application) flag or equivalent. Most regex engines will advance one character after a successful zero-length substring match, but there are exceptions. As a general rule, nullable regexes (including the empty regex) should not be used with a repeated application flag unless the result is explicitly documented by the regex library (and, for what it's worth, I couldn't find such documentation for PostgreSQL, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist somewhere).